# JS FileReader onloadend seems to be causing redirect

Tags: javascript, filereader, http-redirect

I am working on a frontend-intensive project that reads and parses CSVs via a new FileReader. Here is the offending code block, from what I have surmised thanks to Dev Tools:

```
 function parseCSVs() {
  let fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-input')

  if(fileUpload.files.length) {
    let fileReader = new FileReader(),
        varLabels = varAssigner.querySelectorAll('input');

    function _addUntilFull(i) {
      fileReader.readAsText(fileUpload.files[i])
      fileReader.onloadend = function() {
        addVar(varLabels[i].value, csvToMatrix(fileReader.result))

        if(varList.length == fileUpload.files.length) {
          return;
        } else {
          _addUntilFull(i + 1)
        }
      }
    }
    _addUntilFull(0)
  }
```

[Preserved console messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOBl1.png)

After preserving logs (see figure above), I discovered that the console was logging all the correct messages (leading me to think that my functions all work properly), but the document would clear/reload upon file submission and parsing completion, and the logs would say "Navigating to file:///etc/etc", so this problem most likely comes from unexpected behavior on the part of either the FileReader or input[type="file"] objects. I can't find anything in MDN's documentation of FileReader or other online forums that would explain why this is occurring. Please help! This has been such a headache -_-
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually figured out what the problem was, and it had nothing to do with the above code block... The button that triggered the parseCSVs function was inside a form, and even though I had deleted the "action" and "method" attributes of the form, and the button had no "type", the button triggered a redirect after the onclick function fired. I also ran a test on a form and button with no attributes in a bare-bones HTML file and discovered the same behavior as above. Switching the  element to a  prevented the redirect and fixed the problem :)